# Parsing search query from referrer using PHP

Tags: php, switch-statement, http-referer

I'm attempting to grab the search query from search engine referrals. Most pass the search query with the ?q parameter, however yahoo is using ?p so I'm trying to use a switch statement but to no avail. Here is what I have:

```
<?php
$parse = parse_url($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
$se = $parse["host"];
$raw_var = explode("&", $parse["query"] );
foreach ($raw_var as $one_var) {
$raw = explode("=", $one_var);
$var[$raw[0]] = urldecode ($raw[1]);
}
$se = explode (".", $se);
switch ($se[1]) {
case "yahoo":
$sekeyword = $var["p"];
break;
default:
$sekeyword = $var["q"];
}

print_r ($se);
echo "<br>";
echo "search query is: $sekeyword";

?>
```

Here is what I am seeing:

$se = `Array ( [0] => au [1] => search [2] => yahoo [3] => com )`

$sekeyword is null, however if I specify the default $var as "p" within the switch then the search query from yahoo is passed correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're `switch`ing on `$se[1]` but in your case the string "yahoo" is in `$se[2]` ..